# fetching from an array of addresses

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to save all addresses that funded more than 1 ETH by calling the function  `addyFunded1EthOrMore`, however, I keep running into this error "call to FundProject.addyFunded1EthOrMore errored: VM error: revert."

What am I doing wrong?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >0.6.0  <=0.9.0;


// this contract will allow a user to create any project they want to get funded on
// Community can fund the project
contract FundProject {
        
    // mapping which address how much ETH
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    // arrays of addresses who funded 
    address[] public funders;
    // address of the owner
    address public owner;
    
   // first person that calls this is the owner
   constructor() public {
       owner = msg.sender;
   } 

   function fund() public payable {
        
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
   }
   
   function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint) {

       return address(this).balance;    
   }
   function allFunders() public view returns(address  [] memory ) { 

        return funders;
   }
    

    function addyFunded1EthOrMore() public view returns(address  [] memory ) { 
        address[] memory allAddysFunded1EthOrMore;
        uint256 counter = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i <= funders.length; i++) {
            if (addressToAmountFunded[funders[i]] >= 1000000000000000000) {
                allAddysFunded1EthOrMore[counter] = funders[i];
                counter+= 1;
            }
        }
        return allAddysFunded1EthOrMore;
   } // function def - addyFunded1EthOrMore


} // End of contract
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the full error message and the test code

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because of the termination case in your for loop, which is causing an index out of bounds error. `i <= funders.length` will make the for loop run when `i` is equal to `funders.length`, but then when you use `i` as an index in `funders`, the entry `[funders.length]` will be outside the arrays bounds, since they are 0-indexed.

Simply changing that snippet to `i < funders.length` should resolve that issue